# Is there a name for arguing with other people in one's mind?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, consciousness

Is there a name for the phenomenon of arguing with other people in one's mind?
I don't mean simply replaying memories of arguments (or modifications thereof), although that may fall under this too but also predicting arguments and debating people preemptively in one's imagination.

Comment: Thought experiment.

Comment: Thought experiment is an imagined sequence of events. It is used to illustrate or investigate the consequences of a given action or condition, especially in philosophy and theoretical physics. It's not about psychology, it's a method of obtaining insight.

Comment: @ChrisRogers: I do not dispute that thought experiments are used as a insight method in psychology as a science. However, the psychology process describing above is self-talk or an internal monologue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of a term specifically for this phenomenon.

Having a conversation in one's head has been termed dialogic inner speech by [several researchers](https://academic.oup.com/scan/article/11/1/110/2375153).  You didn't mention if the people you are arguing with reply back - if they don't, then it's just regular (monologic) inner speech.

One common function of inner speech is [sometimes referred to](https://psychology.wikia.org/wiki/Internal_monologue) as speech rehearsal - ie, where one might practice a monologue or dialogue (eg, debate) in their mind ahead of time.

In a more pathological context, repeatedly looping through a conversation in one's head can be a form of rumination, and simulating a future argument could be considered [action rumination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumination_(psychology)#Types_and_content_of_thoughts) if it is a reaction to a recently failed argument.

Comment: I meant the people argue back by using the preposition 'with' rather than 'at' or something. Thanks! I'll accept this soon if nobody else answers with something better.

Comment: Good video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRLkDafQbP8